# How to get parent page id and title of current page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Here is the my code, which is not working.

```
global $post;
echo get_the_title( wp_get_post_parent_id( $post->post->ID ) );
```

but this is not working.

thank you in advance.

Comment: what version of Wordpress? Where do you execute this code?

Comment: Latest version, in header.php file

Comment: Dump this variable:  $parent = get_post( $post->post_parent );

Comment: Did not get your point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For parent page id

```
$post->post_parent;
```

For current page title

```
$post->post_title;
```

Comment: Try `$wp_query->post->post_title;`

Answer (score 7):

For parent page id

```
<?php
  echo wp_get_post_parent_id(get_the_ID());
?>
```

Comment: We don't even need to provide `get_the_ID()` as function works by default with `null` value and retrieves global post variable that stores current post ID.

Answer (score 2):

In Gutenberg:

```
wp.data.select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('parent')
```

Hope will be helpful to someone

Answer (score 1):

If you want i.e: create a link to the post parent:

```php
<a href="<?= get_permalink($post->post_parent) ?>">
  <?= get_the_title($post->post_parent) ?>
</a>
&rarr; <?= the_title() ?>
```

which will result in i.e:

> **Latest News** → Some news title

Answer (score 0):

For Astra theme and for page template look.php I did this:
$post->post_parent; will nbot work cause in my case function is out of the loop. I run it via functions.php. $post->post_parent works perfectly when inserting it in page template, but not when editing theme function ;)

```
function add_script_before_header() {

  $current = $post->ID;
  $parent = $post->post_parent;
  $grandparent_get = get_post($parent);
  $grandparent = $grandparent_get->post_parent;

  if ($root_parent = get_the_title($grandparent) !== $root_parent = get_the_title($current)) {
    echo get_the_title($grandparent); 
  }

  $after = $parent;
  if ( is_page_template( 'look.php' ) ) {
            echo $after . ' - ';
  }
}
```